# elastic search date range aggregation not giving complete data

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

**I am Querying for getting aggregate data based on date_range, like below**

```
"aggs": {
        "range": {
            "date_range": {
                "field": "sold",
                "ranges": [
                    {  "from": "2014-11-01", "to": "2014-11-30" },
                    {  "from": "2014-08-01", "to": "2014-08-31" } 
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

**using this I am getting this response**

```
"aggregations": {
    "range": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "2014-08-01T00:00:00.000Z-2014-08-31T00:00:00.000Z",
          "from": 1406851200000,
          "from_as_string": "2014-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "to": 1409443200000,
          "to_as_string": "2014-08-31T00:00:00.000Z",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z-2014-11-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "from": 1414800000000,
          "from_as_string": "2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "to": 1417305600000,
          "to_as_string": "2014-11-30T00:00:00.000Z",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**but instead of only doc_count, I have also required complete aggregate data that satisfy this range,
is threre any way to get this..please help**

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what other fields you're looking for so I've included a couple of examples.

By nesting another **aggs** inside your first one, you can ask Elasticsearch to pull back additional values e.g. [averages](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html), [sums](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html), [counts](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html), min, max, stats, [etc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

this example query will bring back `field_count` - a count of instances of `myfield`
and also return `order_count` - a sum based on a script.

```
"aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "sold",
            "ranges": [
                {  "from": "2014-11-01", "to": "2014-11-30" },
                {  "from": "2014-08-01", "to": "2014-08-31" } 
            ]
        }
    }
},
"aggs" : {
      "field_count": {"value_count" : { "field" : "myfield" }  },
      "order_count": {"sum" : {"script" : " doc[\"output_msgtype\"].value == \"order\" ? 1 : 0"} }  }}
}
```

Comment: Hi ollyc, Thanks, but I want to know how to get actual data which satisfy this condition, please see https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/elasticsearch/4XLDTUkUzgg/XqgghCV5EwkJ

Comment: can you update your question?  your requirement isn't clear - are you asking about the aggregation totals or filtering in the aggregation?

Comment: Hi ollyc, Suppose I have below Data
[
  {
    "price": 20000,
    "color": "red",
    "make": "honda",
    "sold": "2014-11-05"
  },
  {
    "price": 20000,
    "color": "red",
    "make": "honda",
    "sold": "2014-11-05"
  },
  {
    "price": 30000,
    "color": "green",
    "make": "ford",
    "sold": "2014-05-18"
  }
]

I am Querying

       "aggs": {
            "range": {
                "date_range": {
                    "field": "sold",
                    "ranges": [
                        {  "from": "2014-11-01", "to": "2014-11-30" }

                    ]
                }
  cont.

Comment: output is
 
 "aggregations": {
        "range": {
          "buckets": [

            {
              "key": "2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z-2014-11-30T00:00:00.000Z",
              "from": 1414800000000,
              "from_as_string": "2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "to": 1417305600000,
              "to_as_string": "2014-11-30T00:00:00.000Z",
              "doc_count": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      }

from output I am getting that I have two data(doc_count) which come under this range,ok

continue........

Comment: But if i have required those data which satisfies this condition or range like below

  {
    "price": 20000,
    "color": "red",
    "make": "honda",
    "sold": "2014-11-05"
  }

 {
    "price": 20000,
    "color": "red",
    "make": "honda",
    "sold": "2014-11-05"
  }

What I have required to do for this????please help???

Comment: this:  { "price": 20000, "color": "red", "make": "honda", "sold": "2014-11-05" } isn't an aggregation. if you want this, select it in your main query. if you want to bring back a formatted date then include it in your main query too.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking for any sums, counts, averages on your data - then an aggregation isn't going to help.

I would instead run a standard query once per range.  e.g.:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/cars/_search?pretty' -d '{
"fields" : ["price", "color", "make", "sold" ],
"query":{
   "filtered": {   
    "query": {
      "match_all" : { }
    },
 "filter" : {
        "range": {"sold": {"gte": "2014-09-21T20:03:12.963","lte": "2014-09-24T20:03:12.963"}}}
    }
  }
}'
```

repeat this query as needed but modifying the range each time.

Comment: Hi ollyc, THanks, I know this way, I have required to get data based on aggregation(or group by), is it possible to get data through aggregation